# How do I display a static map size even when markers should not overlap each other?

Tags: android

Actually I have to display a map of size 400x400 and that have a list of markers. That marker should not overlap on each other, and even the markers locations are near to each other.

And the map should not do zoom in and zoom out functionality. And whole markers should display on a physical device screen. I tried, and I am able to show whole markers on the device screen, but markers are overlapping.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to implement this class and handle the touch events to disable or enable events in your map: https://github.com/madsbf/MapStateListener